# What‘s different between weakKeys() and weakValues() in Guava Cache?

Tags: java, guava

I know `weakKeys()` means the keys are wrapped by `WeakReference` and GC may collect the keys automatically, same with `weakValues()`(for value).

My understanding: Once an entry (**whether key or value**) was collected by GC, the entry is expired.

My question:

- Are `weakKeys()` and `weakValues()` equivalent? (one of them was collected, the entry is expired)
- Guava doc said: "when this method is used, the resulting cache will use identity (==) comparison to determine equality of values". When the cache compares the value? for what?

Comment: Regarding the equality of values, it needs to be noted that the behavior of the cache entry (key/value/both) is changed. `cache.getIfPresent(new String("KEY"))` and `cache.getIfPresent(new String("KEY"))` will not fetch you the same entry using weak or soft keys. When configuring using weakValues, if you call `cache.asMap().containsValue("EXPECTED")` then it will only return true if the object has the same reference (`==`) in contrast to the default behavior using object `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

> `Are weakKeys()` and `weakValues()` equivalent? (one of them was collected, the entry is expired)

No, if a key or value is collected, the `Entry` itself will not expire. You will still have access to the `Entry`, but the "reference" to the key and value will point you to `null`.

> Guava doc said: "when this method is used, the resulting cache will use identity (==) comparison to determine equality of values". When the cache compares the value? for what?

In Java, `Object` variables are basically pointers, which means they store an `8-bit` address in the memory block containing the object. So, the documentation says that it will not compare objects (because they are `null`), but references to objects.